# Access denied for Database User at goDaddy website

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to view my website from godaddy. The domain name is registered on somewhere else and hosting is from godaddy. After changing DNS settings, I cretae my db in godaddy and import all tables in it. After that, i created a username and give it to all previleges. Then, when i tried to connect to database, i am facing error

```
Access denied for user 'myusername'@'ip-166-62-28-82.ip.secureserver.net' (using password: YES)
```

db.php

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("166.62.28.82", "myusername","mypassword", "arikai2_2" ) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("arikai2_2");

?>
```

Comment: Your mysql password is wrong if that's the **correct** host.

Comment: The *Remote access* is allowed ?

Comment: @PanamaJack
But i am using same password that i set at the time of create "database username and password"

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH
What do you mean ?

Comment: He means that check if the database you created has been enabled to access remote connections. Because that DB is not on the same server as your site, which is why you are using the IP address instead of localhost. Maybe look at this [info here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-databases-remotely-16103)

Comment: @PanamaJack
Means i have to add same ip address that i am using in my query.
Right?

Comment: I added the same address in "Host access list". Now on preview page, it is demanding credentials.
On giving db-username and pass and even ftp username and password, it is saying "wrong credentials"
What type of credentials are required here?

Comment: this questions needs much better info. Like, a webserver is at ip address w.x.y.z and it wants to communicate with mysql which is at a.b.c.d . And the website is hosted on Hostgator with web service package name (cheap hosting plan, VPS, etc) ... and I have set up the following user accts on the mysql server here ---> (info) ... note, we dont need actual IP addresses. Right now, no one has the first clue what you are talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you get the dbhost value from?

In your hosting panel, there should be somewhere a section where you can get the right details about connecting to your database server and its databases.

If you are using the classic goDaddy hosting, you can find this info in the:
 **Databases > MySQL Section > Actions > Details**
The dbhost is down at the bottom of this screen: **Hostname**

[image: GoDaddy Classic Hosting Panel]
[image: GoDaddy Classic Hosting Databases]
[image: GoDaddy Classic Hosting Database Details]

Comment: I am using linux based hosting with godaddy. And there in Cpanel, i don't have the structure that you showed me !

Comment: For anyone still coming to this question & answer - just go here: https://au.godaddy.com/help/find-your-database-hostname-23889 to find out how to get your dbhostname

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the mysql host is correct. You can contact your hosting provider to help you getting the proper host for your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having issue even after correct username,password and database name, reset your database user's password and update it in your mysqli connection code. This is weird but it worked for me.